# Deploying multiple WebServices with identical serviceName in Java EE 6

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish

I'm running in problems if i want deploy two webservices with identical serviceName (but different targetNamespace) in one Java EE 6 EJB module.

Here my setup:

my-webservice-ejb.jar

- src/main/java/ 
  -- de.xx.**MyService1**.java 
  @Stateless(name="**MyServiceEJB1**") 
  @WebService(targetNamespace="http://**de.xx**", serviceName="**MyService**", portName="MyServicePort", wsdlLocation="META-INF/wsdl/**MyService1.wsdl**") 
  -- de.xx.**MyService2**.java 
  @Stateless(name="**MyServiceEJB2**") 
  @WebService(targetNamespace="http://**de.xx.v2**", serviceName="**MyService**", portName="MyServicePort", wsdlLocation="META-INF/wsdl/**MyService2.wsdl**")
- src/main/resources/META-INF/wsdl/ 
  -- **MyService1.wsdl** (defines **MyService** with targetNamespace **http://de.xx**) 
  -- **MyService2.wsdl** (defines **MyService** with targetNamespace **http://de.xx.v2**)

Glassfish runns in this error by deployment:

Cannot initialize endpoint  : error is : 
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: WSDL file/my-webservice-ejb.jar/META-INF/wsdl/MyService1.wsdl 
has the following services [{http://de.xx}MyService] but not {http://de.xx.v2}MyService. 
Maybe you forgot to specify a serviceName and/or targetNamespace in @WebService/@WebServiceProvider?

If i split both service EJB's (same code & annotation) in different ejb.jar's (my-webservice1-ejb.jar & my-webservice2-ejb.jar) deployment runs without any problems.